# Reflux.utils.environment is undefined. Why?

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I have the next code and I don't understand why it doesn't work now.

The next code inits Reflux that I use in my project:

```
module.exports = {
   configure: function () {
       var Reflux = require('reflux');
       Reflux.utils.environment.hasPromise = true;
       Reflux.setPromiseFactory(require('q').Promise);
    }
};
```

And Reflux.utils.environment is undefined.

Can this be linked with versions of some modules in the project?
What can be the reason of this thing?

Thanks!